# QML ListView Model setProperty Work only 1 time

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qt6

I have a ListView filled with checkboxes, I want to change the checkbox status from a button click this is my code.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ListView {
        id: mylist
        width: parent.width
        height: 300
        anchors {
            top: parent.top
            left: parent.left
            right: parent.right
            bottom: change_state.top
            bottomMargin: 20
        }

        model: ListModel {
            id: mymodel
            ListElement {
                mystatus : false
            }
            ListElement {
                mystatus : false
            }
            ListElement {
                mystatus : false
            }
        }

        delegate: Rectangle {
            height: 50
            width: parent.width
            CheckBox {
                id: cb
                checked: mystatus
                anchors.fill: parent
                text: "State"
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: change_state
        anchors {
            bottom: parent.bottom
        }
        text: "Change status"

        onClicked: {
            mymodel.setProperty(1, "mystatus", true)
            console.log("PRESSED")
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I press the button after running the app it changes the status and checks the box, but if I remove the check manually then press the button again it has 0 effects, never been able to check it again.

QT 6.3
Windows 10
same issue for Android, IOS, and Desktop.

Tested with QT 5.15.2 and the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on the checkbox itself, you break the binding. Initially the `checked` property is bound to `mystatus`. But when you check the box manually, you're forcing `checked` to be true or false, regardless of the state of `mystatus`.

You can keep the binding intact by catching the onClicked signal and updating `mystatus`, rather than forcing the `checked` value to change.

```
CheckBox {
    id: cb
    checked: mystatus
    anchors.fill: parent
    text: "State"

    onClicked: {
        mystatus = !mystatus
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For your added question of unchecking all the boxes, you should do the same thing as above and update the mystatus value in the model rather than directly touching the `checked` property so that the binding doesn't get broken.

```
for (var i = 0; i < mymodel.count; ++i) {
    mymodel.setProperty(i, "mystatus", false);
}
```